# XUL: create menu items dynamically and set "selected" attr

Tags: xul, firefox-addon, javascript

I have a firefox extension Options pref panel, where I should dynamically create menu items and select particular item to be current.

here is the XUL file part

```
<menulist id="rss_service_combo">
    <menupopup id="rss_service_menu"/>
</menulist>
```

Then in `load` event of the pref panel, using js I append `menuitem` elements into `menupop`. This is working fine. The only problem is that even if I set the `selected` element the item is not selected and combo box is initially empty.

The only way is working at the moment is if I manually add those `menuitem`s into XUL file and set `selected` attribute, but I need to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menulist#p-selectedIndex) attribute. Here's some sample code for adding menu items dynamically:

```
// In a for loop...
var menuItem = document.createElement("menuitem");
menuItem.setAttribute("oncommand", "alert('Hi!');");
menuItem.setAttribute("label", basename);
aMenu.appendChild(menuItem);
```